# MediaWiki migration to Sharepoint 2013 / link correction

Tags: migration

I am trying to migrate my old `MediaWiki` to `Sharepoint 2013`. I used the `Content Matrix` tool from metalogix. It worked, but all the internal links are still addressed to the MediaWiki. The Tool has the function to fix/correct the links. But its too expensive for me to buy the commercial. Anyone knows how to do this on a other way?